# A filter that only runs once?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I made a filter that replaces a key with a translation.

```
<label>{{'city' | translate}}</label>
```

The filter simply looks up the key `city` in a json file and returns the value.

What I didn't realize is that filters are run... a lot. After some research I see that there are better ways to do this but I am not willing to do a complete refactor.

How can I simply tell this filter to only run once per key.

As a workaround, I am pre-compiling the templates and replacing calls to `translate` with the correct string. This works for most cases but there are places where the key is dynamic or the translation is a function that takes scope variable as arguments

```
<label>{{'greeting' | translate:firstName:lastName}}</label>
```

I want Angular to just do a one-time replace of these and never think about it again.

Comment: Add you filter definition to the question.

Comment: You could have a look at angular-once, which is designed not to set up watchers: https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once

Comment: @Stewie its proprietary, but all filters run very $digest if I understand them correctly. Can the specific implementation affect how often they are run?

Comment: Filter functions, as well as any other function, can be cached. In case your filtering logic is expensive, caching would help.

Comment: It is not expensive, it is a simple lookup. There are just a lot of them and there is no reason for them to be run more than once. The data behind them is not dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want Angular to just do a one-time replace of these and never think about it again.

This is a little ambiguous. What if the scope variable changes? Do you want the filter to run each time it changes? Or do you really mean that when the DOM is first compiled, whatever value the scope variable has then should be passed to the filter, evaluated and statically set to the DOM? If the latter, I recommend [angular-bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), which provides watchless binding from the scope to the DOM.

After adding the module as a dependency to your app, the markup would look like:

`<label bo-text="city|translate"</label>`

Comment: I think you have correctly understood my intention: no watchers.

Comment: Even if you use a directive that executes once per instantiation every time your controller reloads it will re-fire.

Comment: @DanKanze - in what situation are you imagining the controller would reload?

Answer (score 3):

Translate the object value itself before returning it to your view:

```
$scope.city = city.$translate();
```

That way you aren't running the filter everytime you reload a template or `ng-repeat`

```
<label>{{city}}</label>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not feasible. I would not be able to do this for hundreds of translations. I would have to pull out the translations used in each template and add them to the controller. Name collisions would be a huge hassle and they would not work for the complex ones that occur in ng-repeats.

Comment: I feel your pain that it's a lot of work but you would add them to a service not a controller - that's what those things are for. You could effectively run thousands of translations without a performance hit because it's just a key name lookup. Can you describe in detail why this would not work for `ng-repeat`?

Comment: It wouldn't work because the controller doesn't necessarily know which translations will be needed by the view. I could iterate over the data first in the controller, but that is not the sort of solution I am looking for. I specifically do not want to have to refactor my project if it is avoidable.

Comment: That's why I said you need to use a service. Think of the type of inheritance you need to do something like this. If you want to translate a bunch of strings over multiple controllers, then those "things" should all be coming from a singular place, like a service.

Comment: Agreed. The problem is getting from here to their with the least amount of work.